# List sorting in CMake 3.12

Tags: cmake

I'd missing something basic in CMake.
This code:

```
set(MyList "a" "b" "c")
list(SORT "${MyList}")
```

Runs fine in CMake 3.14, but fails in 3.12 with this error:

```
list sub-command SORT requires list to be present.
```

The documentation for [list](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/list.html) doesn't say anything specific.
Were there some changes done in 3.14 in the are of list handling? 
What is the proper way to sort a list in 3.12?

Comment: It's `list(SORT MyList)`.

Comment: Oh, nice, indeed. @KamilCuk, can you point to the documentation?

Comment: It's the documentation you linked.

Answer (score 1):

This was a silly mistake.
The CMake 3.14 added different handling of list variables. Now `"${MyList}"` is acceptable. In the previous versions only `MyList` must be used.